# Enable Wol settings programmatically in windows service

Tags: c#, wake-on-lan

Is there any way to set the WOL(wake-on-lan) settings programmatically with c#?
I've found few ways with powershell script but needed with c#.

[image]

I need a way to check/uncheck the power management settings with c# in windows service. Is it only possible by running powershell script with c#?

Answer (score 0):

You can try starting the powershell script from c#